# Close Dialog with DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

We have a requirement to close forms, during auto log off. We are closing dialogs by iterating forms in `Application.OpenForms`

We cannot close a dialog if the dialog has a date time control (`DateTimePicker`) with the calender window is activive as shown in the following image

http://ww.functionx.com/vcnet/controls/images/Calendar4.gif

I tried to close the form by calling `Close` Method. It didn't work.

Then I sent the WM_CLOSE message to close the calender window as shown below after enumerating the windows and then called `Close` on the form. In this case the Calender window closed. But the form did not close

```
if (sb.ToString() == "SysMonthCal32")
{
    SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0010, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);             
}
```

In both cases, if I click on the Dialog it closed.

How can I close the form?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to duplicate your problem, this is, a call to form.Close() caused the form to close whether the date picker control was opened up or not.  (also got same result by using PostMessage WM_CLOSE to form's hwnd)

I did find that I could make the date-picker control "close up" by calling its Hide and then Show methods:

```
dateTimePicker1.Hide();
dateTimePicker1.Show();
```

This also has the advantage of not destroying any window objects, as Close (or WM_CLOSE) might do.